# How to convert the : char into a newline in a file by python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, file, file-copying

I am having a text file in which data is in this form:

Before formatting:

```
a1 ,a2,a3:b1 ,b2,b3:c1 ,c2,c3:....so on.
```

Now i want to convert the data in this particular form:

After formatting:

```
a1,a2,a3
b1,b2,b3
c1,c2,c3
...so on
```

To do: first i want to convert `:` char in 'newline' and want to recover the space after every first character such as `a1 b1 c1`. the space is creating problem as the data after formatting is to be converted into csv file.

I tried transferring one by one char from one file to other in which i used an if case to replace `:` to 'newline'.
For newline I used this `\n`

`file.txt` is file which contain `a1 ,a2,a3:b1 ,b2,b3:c1 ,c2,c3:....so on`

`convert.txt` if file in which i want formatted data

```
with open('file.txt','r') as rf:
    with open('convert.txt','w') as wf:
        a=1
        rf_temp = rf.read(a)
        while len(rf_temp) > 0:
            if rf_temp == ':':
                rf_temp.replace(':','\n')
            wf.write(rf_temp)
            rf_temp = rf.read(a)
    wf.close()
rf.close
```

the data gets copied clearly but not in format which i want including ':' this symbol.
There are no issues in copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# define the input file and output file
inputFile = 'test.txt'
outFile = "test.csv"

# read data from input file
data = open(inputFile).read()

# change data to wanted format, using '\n' to replace ':'
data = "\n".join(data.split(':'))

# save the changed data to output file
outF = open(outFile, 'w')
outF.write(data)

print(data)
```

output

```py
a1 ,a2,a3
b1 ,b2,b3
c1 ,c2,c3
```

Comment: Glad to help. If this code helped, please upvote and accept it.^_^

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.join` with `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
print("\n".join("a1 ,a2,a3:b1 ,b2,b3:c1 ,c2,c3".split(":")))
```

**Output:**

```
a1 ,a2,a3
b1 ,b2,b3
c1 ,c2,c3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "a1 ,a2,a3:b1 ,b2,b3:c1 ,c2,c3"
b = a.split(":")
for i in b:
    print(i)
```

if  you need  one line solution you can do it in the following way

```
print("\n".join(a.split(":")))
```